# Libpng vulnerability issue

Tags: android, libpng, android-security

Hi I'm using the following dependencies in my project Gradle and I have update all the packages so far but every time after uploading google play console rejecting my app saying Libpng vulnerability issue.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile files('src/libs/xmlpull_1.1.3.1.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile project(':nikon_lib')
compile project(':hgrid_lib')
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.8'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.8'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.8'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.3.8'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
transitive = true;
}
```

After running the Gradle dependency script `./gradlew app:dependencies` I got the tree structure which I have shown below but still I couldn't find what dependency is using Libpng library

```
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:10.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:10.0.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:10.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:10.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:24.0.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:palette-v7:24.0.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 -> 25.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0 -> 25.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.0.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.0.1
|    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.0.1 (*)
|    |              \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:10.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:10.0.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:10.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.0.1 (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4
+--- project :nikon_lib
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0 (*)
+--- project :hgrid_lib
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.8
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4 -> 2.4
+--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.8
|    \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.8 (*)
+--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.8
|    \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.8 (*)
+--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.3.8
|    \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.8 (*)
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1
|    \--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
\--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.2
|    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.13 -> 1.3.14
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.14
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10 (*)
  \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
```

Comment: Note that you're using an old OkHttp version. Try upgrading that to [v3](http://square.github.io/okhttp/#download) and then re-upload (*I'm not sure whether they use it, but it's worth a shot*). I think the gradle dependency won't show libpng because it's not a normal dependency but a compiled library in .so format in most libraries.

Comment: @ Gergely Kőrössy. Tried it. Didn't work

Comment: Well, I can only think of one tedious solution: create a new project and add the dependencies in groups (like 5 dependencies at a time), then upload it to Google Play. If it rejects the APK at one of the groups, you can narrow it down to that one and add the dependencies one by one to see which one causes it.

Comment: @ Gergely Kőrössy. Is there any way to clear all the downloaded packages in local from the dependencies. Maybe ever after updating if any old files still exist it may show this error.

Comment: A clear project should help. However, it shouldn't show any errors related to old packages in the dev console since it uses only the dependencies you include in your build.gradle file, not what you've downloaded ever before.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are inside your project directory and the Android application directory is named `app`, run the command:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

This will show the package dependencies tree, revealing which one requires `libpng`.

Comment: should i run this command in the terminal available in android studio ?

Comment: @sridhars terminal

Comment: Checked it but none of the packages a re showing any Libpng dependencies

Comment: I have edited my question and have showed the tree structure generated with the above command that you mentioned but still I couldn't find it. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, libpng was compiled in to a native executable, and gradle doesn't know about it. You could try `grep`ing for "libpng" in all of the .so files. The filename of the .so should give a clue to where it came from.